# asynctask progress dialog part of main UI?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runnable

I have an asynctask thread running which has a progress dialog shown.  While it running, i also have another runnable thread which updates the UI.  However it seems that updating the UI seems to lock up progress dialog until it finishes the update.  Is the progress dialog in a separate asynctask part of the main UI?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `onProgressUpdate` of `AsyncTask` to show progress (i.e. update the UI). Overrive the method like this -

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    YOUR_ACTIVITY_INSTANCE.setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
}
```

You can call the `publishProgress` method from `doInBackground` to trigger `onProgressUpdate` and update the UI (like showing percentage if required).